# Automatic Membership Status Jobs Fails on Cron Run

Tags: civimember, cron-job

We have setup the automated Cron job to run on the server every 15 minutes. This works great for newsletters and other jobs. However when it comes to the membership status job it always fails after running partially. I just get a error 500 from the server. We are trying to identify if it could be due to a particular membership type, membership record or CiviCRM.

We have updated CiviCRM a couple of times and the it is on the most stable long term versions i.e. 4.6.38 and Drupal 7.6x.

1. Has anyone come across this error?
2. In the command parameters can we add a command to run only by certain membership types? Does anyone know what this command will be? This way we can debug the issue in more detail.

Comment: How many members do you have?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the CiviCRM log file?  Typically under `sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog`

Comment: There are about 5000 Members and 35K contacts. Can't find anything in the log files. It just shows an error 500. Any other ideas? Thanks.